# Javascript Cookie not being created

Tags: javascript, forms, email, cookies

I have this code referencing a form on my site to create a cookie

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function storeValues(form)  
 {
   setCookie("signup[email]", form.signup[email].value);    
   return true;
  }
```

The cookie is not created though! any ideas??

url: aximit.com/wifi/pagecookie.php

edit here is the method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var today = new Date();
var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days

function setCookie(name, value)
{
document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the setCookie method ?

Comment: what about your `session.cookie_httponly` flag?

Comment: here is the setCookie method:<script type="text/javascript">

  var today = new Date();
  var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days

  function setCookie(name, value)
  {
    document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
  }

Comment: Your code seems to be fine see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/XwhLu/). There is something else that is not working

Comment: Anything you can spot that would be stopping it?

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
function storeValues(form)  
{
  setCookie("signup[email]", form.elements["signup[email]"].value);    
  return true;
}
```

`form.elements` returns all the elements within the form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it still didn't work though. `<script type="text/javascript">
  var today = new Date();
  var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days

  function setCookie(name, value)
  {
    document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
  }` That is the script